# vpnc gets stuck with "Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "ipid" is a garbage."

Tags: linux, vpn

Sometimes when vpnc gets interrupted in the middle of establishing or breaking a connection, it gets 'stuck': when i run vpnc-disconnect, i get `no vpnc found running`, but when i try to run vpnc-connect, i get `Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "ipid" is a garbage.`, and after getting that message the network stops working and i must disconnect and reconnect my network connection.

Rebooting or waiting about a day fixes the problem. Is there a way to get it unstuck without rebooting or waiting a day?

Presumably there is a problem either with something called "to" or something called "ipid" which times out eventually. What is "to" and what is "ipid"?

I'm using vpnc Ubuntu package version 0.5.3r449-2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10, kernel 3.0.0-16-generic.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Googling for a similar problem it turned out there was a typo in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth*` file. 
Missing the '`dev`' word from "`10.0.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1`**`dev`**`eth2`"

Hope it helps.